# How does Java implement LinkedLists

Tags: java, pointers

Java does not have the concept of pointers . So how does java implement the implicitly available linkedList or even make a shallow copy for that matter ?

Comment: FWIW: the java.util.LinkedList is a double-linked list that also knows its length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java does have references that can point to another object, or null. That is all that is needed for a linked list.

You do the general purpose linked list in C by having a struct for node, likewise, the LinkedList would in Java contain also a private class for a node with reference to the actual value, and 1 or more references to the node class for links.

Comment: So is it possible to create our own linked lists in Java ?

Comment: It is indeed possible to create your own linked list in java. It is in fact, much easier than doing the same in C, as java's memory management means that you don't have to worry about freeing as you would in C.

Comment: The source for java.util.LinkedList - surprisingly enough, written in Java: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/LinkedList.java.html

Answer (score 4):

Java has references.  These are like pointers except that you cannot do things like pointer arithmetic, or casting pointers to integers and vice-versa.

Naturally, linked lists are implemented using references.

---

The reasons that Java eschews pointer arithmetic and conversion between integers and pointers include:

- to eliminate a major source of bugs, and
- to make it possible to implement full-function (i.e non-conservative, non-reference counting, high performance) garbage collection.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly easily implement your own linked lists in Java. You can also use the [java.util.LinkedList Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

Here is a simple LinkedList implementation from Ivor Horton's book "Beginning Java":

```
public class LinkedList {
  // Default constructor - creates an empty list
  public LinkedList() {}

  // Constructor to create a list containing one object
  public LinkedList(Object item) {
    if(item != null) {
      current=end=start=new ListItem(item); // item is the start and end
    }
  }

  // Construct a linked list from an array of objects
  public LinkedList(Object[] items) {
    if(items != null) {
      // Add the items to the list
      for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        addItem(items[i]);
      }
      current = start;
    }
  }

  // Add an item object to the list
  public void addItem(Object item) {
    ListItem newEnd = new ListItem(item);   // Create a new ListItem
    if(start == null) {                     // Is the list empty?
      start = end = newEnd;                 // Yes, so new element is start and end
    } else {                                // No, so append new element
      end.next = newEnd;                    // Set next variable for old end
      end = newEnd;                         // Store new item as end 
    }
  }

  // Get the first object in the list
  public Object getFirst() {
    current = start;
    return start == null ? null : start.item;
  }

  // Get the next object in the list
  public Object getNext() {
    if(current != null) {
      current = current.next;        // Get the reference to the next item
    }
    return current == null ? null : current.item;
  }

  private ListItem start = null;         // First ListItem in the list
  private ListItem end = null;           // Last ListItem in the list
  private ListItem current = null;       // The current item for iterating
  private class ListItem {
    // Constructor 
    public ListItem(Object item) {
      this.item = item;                  // Store the item
      next = null;                       // Set next as end point
    }

    // Return class name & object
    public String toString() {
      return "ListItem " + item ;
    }

    ListItem next;                       // Refers to next item in the list
    Object item;                         // The item for this ListItem
  }
}
```

Comment: I am aware of the implicit LinkedList but was very keen to implement my own . Thanks for the motivation :)